# Knapsack but exact weight

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

Is there a algorithm to determine a knapsack which has an exact weight W? I.e. it's like the normal 0/1 knapsack problem with n items each having weight w_i and value v_i. Maximise the value of all the items, however the **total weight of the items in the knapsack need to have exactly weight W**!

I know the "normal" 0/1 knapsack algorithm but this could also return a knapsack with less weight but higher value. I want to find the highest value but exact W weight.

Here is my 0/1 knapsack implementation:

```
public class KnapSackTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] w = new int[] {4, 1, 5, 8, 3, 9, 2};  //weights
        int[] v = new int[] {2, 12, 8, 9, 3, 4, 3}; //values

        int n = w.length;
        int W = 15; // W (max weight)

        int[][] DP = new int[n+1][W+1];

        for(int i = 1; i < n+1; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < W+1; j++) {
                if(i == 0 || j == 0) {
                    DP[i][j] = 0;
                } else if (j - w[i-1] >= 0) {
                    DP[i][j] = Math.max(DP[i-1][j], DP[i-1][j - w[i-1]] + v[i-1]);
                } else {
                    DP[i][j] = DP[i-1][j];
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Result: " + DP[n][W]);
    }
}
```

This gives me:

```
Result: 29
```

(Just ask if anything is unclear in my question!)

Comment: Just switch `DP[i][j] = DP[i-1][j];` to `DP[i][j] = -infinity`

Comment: @greybeard whoops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By simply setting `DP[i][j] = -infinity` in your last `else` clause it will do the trick.

The ides behind it is to slightly change the recursive formula definition to calculate:

- Find the maximal value with **exactly** weight `j` up to item `i`.

Now, the induction hypothesis will change, and the proof of correctness will be very similar to regular knapsack with the following modification:

DP[i][j-weight[i]] is now the maximal value that can be constructed with exactly `j-weight[i]`, and you can either take item `i`, giving value of `DP[i][j-weight[i]]`, or not taking it, giving value of `DP[i-1][j]` - which is the maximal value when using exactly weight `j` with first `i-1` items.

Note that if for some reason you cannot construct `DP[i][j]`, you will never use it, as the value -infinity will always discarded when looking for MAX.

Comment: for weights = {1, 2, 2, 4, 5}, values = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1} and W = 6. It gives answer as 3 where as the answer is 2 (because exact weight is obtained by including items with weight 2 and 4). Can you please help me on this?

Answer (score 5):

Actually, the accepted answer is wrong, as found by @Shinchan in the comments.

You get exact weight knapsack by changing only the initial `dp` state, not the algorithm itself.

The initialization, instead of:

```
            if(i == 0 || j == 0) {
                DP[i][j] = 0;
            }
```

should be:

```
            if (j == 0) {
                DP[i][j] = 0;
            } else if (i == 0 && j > 0) { // obviously `&& j > 0` is not needed, but for clarity
                DP[i][j] = -inf;
            }
```

The rest stays as in your question.