How to check if some number can be retrieved as the result of the summation or difference of the given numbers
I have an arbitrary list of positive integers and some number X. I want to check if it is possible to retrieve X using basic operations such as summation and difference.
Any number from the list can be used only once. There might be duplicates.
We can use any amount of numbers from the list to get X, i.e. we can use just one element, two elements also can be used and it is possible to use all elements from the list.
Only True/False answer is enough.
E. g.:
input_list=[1, 7, 3]
X = 4

result: TRUE  (e.g.: 7-3)
input_list=[1, 7, 3]
X = 50

result: FALSE
I have attempted to utilize the approach from this question: Find all combinations of a list of numbers with a given sum,
specifically this part:
[seq for i in range(len(numbers), 0, -1)
 for seq in itertools.combinations(numbers, i)
 if sum(seq) == target]

My idea was to concat the initial list with the list of the opposite integers:
new_list = input_list+list(map(lambda x: -x, input_list))

Then I'm checking if the list comprehension operation described above returns non empty list.
But this takes too much time, what I do not like is that there is some sort of duplication in this approach, itertools.combinations may take 1 and it's opposite -1 twice, but I have no idea how to fix that.
What is the most effecient way of solving such problem?

The linked question needs to find all combinations. You only need to find out if any combination exists. This can be viewed as a form of the 0-1 knapsack problem where the numbers act as both weight and value, applied to your new_list containing the negative copies. You can solve that reasonably efficiently with dynamic programming. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47608725/knapsack-but-exact-weight

You're asking what the most efficient way of solving this problem is, but I suspect you just need a way that works that's not very inefficient? (which is a different question)  How large is the list of inputs, considering you say "this takes too much time" for the beginnings of a solution you had with itertools.combinations?

7-3+1 = 5, so why would your second example's output be False?

Note also that adding all opposites to the original list would allow sums like -3-7 = -10, which you might want - or not.

Another thing to note is that you didn't specify the exact problem, for example, can numbers be reused? Are there duplicate numbers in the list? Are combinations of more than one numbers allowed, or are you only looking for pairings? Are you only interested in a true/false answer, or do you need the actual solution? Please be specific and share your own attempt, no matter the performance.

Thanks for the feedback to everyone, I've updated the question to make it more clear. As for the my attempt, that is basically the copypaste from the linked question (but the initial list of integers is combined with its opposites)

What do you mean by "such as" in "basic operations such as summation and difference"? Depending on whether you include * or % into this list, the answers might be drastically different.

This could be modelled as a linear integer program with each variable required to equal 0 or 1. Let L be the given list of natural numbers, with the ith number designated Li. Let the variable Pi equal 1 if Li is to be included in the sum, else equal 0, and let Ni equal 1 if -Li is to be included in the sum, else equal 0. The single constraint is SUM(over i)LiPi + SUM(over i)-LiNi = X.  The  objective function is arbitrary (say max 0P1). If, for some i, Pi = 1 and Ni = 1 at the optimum set Pi = 0 and Ni = 0.

For each number in the list, you have to make a decision whether:

you add the number
you subtract the number
you drop the number

Here is a solution with breadth-first search of the decision tree:
def isRepresentable(input_list, num):
  reachable = { 0 }
  for n in input_list:
    reachable = { y for x in reachable for y in [x, x + n, x - n] }
    if num in reachable:
      return True
  return False

print(isRepresentable([1, 7, 3], 4))   # True
print(isRepresentable([1, 7, 3], 50))  # False
print(isRepresentable([1, 7, 3], 5))   # True

The BFS finds the shorter solutions, but DFS should be fine as well for true / false answers.
If one also wants to see how the number can be constructed, one has to save the path that lead to that number:
def findRepresentation(input_list, num):
  reachable = { 0: [] }
  for n in input_list:
    next_reachable = dict(reachable)
    for x in reachable:
      for y in [x, x + n, x - n]:
         if y not in next_reachable:
           next_reachable[y] = [*(reachable[x]), y - x]
           if num == y:
             return next_reachable[y]
    reachable = next_reachable
  return None

def explain(input_list, num):
  print(f'Using {input_list}')
  print(f'{num} = {findRepresentation(input_list, num)}')

explain([1, 7, 3], 4)   # 4 = [1, 3]
explain([1, 7, 3], 50)  # None
explain([1, 7, 3], 5)   # 5 = [1, 7, -3]

hundred_primes = [
  2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 
  31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 
  71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 
  109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 
  157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 
  197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233, 239, 
  241, 251, 257, 263, 269, 271, 277, 281, 
  283, 293, 307, 311, 313, 317, 331, 337, 
  347, 349, 353, 359, 367, 373, 379, 383, 
  389, 397, 401, 409, 419, 421, 431, 433, 
  439, 443, 449, 457, 461, 463, 467, 479, 
  487, 491, 499, 503, 509, 521, 523, 541
]
explain(hundred_primes, 2024)

Not that anybody asked, but 2024 can be represented as the sum of the first 33 prime numbers if one skips 103:
2024 = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139]


A naive approach would be of O(N ^ 2) time complexity:
def _diff(nums, x):
    n = len(nums)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i + 1, n):
            if nums[i] + nums[j] == x or abs(nums[i] - nums[j]) == x:
                return True
    return False


print(_diff([1, 7, 3], 4))
print(_diff([1, 7, 3], 5))



We can use set() to make it slightly more efficient:
def check_sum_diff(nums, x):
    S = set(nums)
    for num in nums:
        if (x + num in S) or (num - x in S):
            return True
    return False


print(check_sum_diff([1, 7, 3], 4))
print(check_sum_diff([1, 7, 3], 5))


Prints
True
False


You only test combinations of 2 numbers, while the OP expects to find combinations of any length.

@ThierryLathuille I missed that. Thanks!
